# Reset Keyboard Preferences

Tags: command-line, keyboard

When I first installed Ubuntu it worked flawlessly and the sound control buttons on my keyboard worked as expected. But now I just configured volume up, volume down, and mute to other key combos but when I  set them back to their default keys they don’t work anymore.

So I was guessing if there was a way to reset the functions each key to stock Ubuntu state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open a Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/
```

It will restore the default settings for all your media keys.