# How do I take a screenshot in Ubuntu with a chromebook?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, chromebook, screenshot

I'm using a Chromebook and this keyboard doesn't have a "Print" button, I'm just confused as to what I would use instead of that for taking a screenshot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The default command to take screenshot is actually `gnome-screenshot`, there's several command-line flags that you can provide in addition to that, such as `gnome-screenshot -w` for taking a window screenshot. Knowing this you can assign a custom keyboard shortcut via  System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts. I would suggest using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>  since I don't recall any other application using it, however you are free to choose among the myriad of other possible combinations.

See also: https://askubuntu.com/a/542185/295286

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of terminal apps that will take screenshots without the use of any keyboard function (aside from having a keyboard as input)

My personal favorite is `screenfetch` as it will print out computer info as well

Examples:

usage: `screenfetch -s`

output:
[image: Web-Browser]
[image: Terminal]

See also: https://github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch

you can install it by `sudo apt-get install screenfetch scrot`

Comment: `screenfetch` looks quite interesting. Learned something new, +1

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy neofetch claims to be an improvement over screenfetch.

Comment: @DKBose https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Neofetch-vs-Screenfetch :'D I'll skim through the code now, but I'm curious if you know of any of their claims of "improvements" (not to say there aren't any!)

Comment: @j-money I mostly prefer to use `inxi` but I do remember reading the sort of claims I mentioned. I looked at your link which now has WIP. There are some sites that store archived versions of web pages (Back in Time, or something like that?) but it's a bit unusual to pull a page the way it's happened.

Comment: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Neofetch-vs-Screenfetch/f07119fb9854f5b2c4e40574aebcb41fa4e14806 has an old version and previous revisions are here: https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Neofetch-vs-Screenfetch/_history But as I said, I don't track neofetch or screenfetch enough to know what's really going on there.